# Display status message on JLabel instead of console

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I need to print my game status messages such as players' turns, players' scores using JLabel or something similar. I am able to do so on console (`System.out.print()`).

Basically, I have

```
JLabel statusBar, playerA, playerB; // Where I need to display scores and a message saying where each player have put their seeds on the grid
JPanel mainPanel; //Which holds the grid
JPanel leftPanel; // On which the status bar and other components are put
```

I can display those in the console with:

```
System.out.print("Path : " );
        for(Cell cell : this) {
            System.out.print(cell);
        }
        System.out.println("");

        List<Cell> capturedSeeds = getCapturedWithIn();     

        if(capturedSeeds.size() <= 1) {
            System.out.print(capturedSeeds.size() + " " + "seed captured at: " );
            for(Cell cell : capturedSeeds) {
            System.out.print(cell);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        } else
            if(capturedSeeds.size() >= 2) {
        System.out.print(capturedSeeds.size() + " " + " seeds captured at: " );
        for(Cell cell : capturedSeeds) {
            System.out.print(cell);
        }
        System.out.println("");

        }
```

With the above, I can print something like bellow in the console:

```
>> PION_ROUGE placed at (10,15)
 >> PION_BLEU placed at (11,15)
 >> PION_ROUGE placed at (11,16)
 >> PION_BLEU placed at (10,16)
 >> PION_ROUGE placed at (12,15)
 >> PION_BLEU placed at (12,16)

Path : [11, 14]-PION_ROUGE[10, 15]-PION_ROUGE[11, 16]-PION_ROUGE[12, 15]-PION_ROUGE
1 seed captured at: [11, 15]-PION_BLEU

 >> PION_BLEU placed at (11,17)
 >> PION_ROUGE placed at (19,16)
 >> PION_BLEU placed at (16,14)
 >> PION_ROUGE placed at (17,14)
```

I'm not experienced at all, this question may be silly to ask, but please bear with me.
Fell free to ask any clarification.

Comment: Beware that Swing is single thread and NOT thread safe. This means that if your operation is long running (or blocks for some reason), you will need to perform the operation on separate thread, but, you should also never update the the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. To this end a `SwingWorker` might be suitable to perform the long running operations, as it provides the ability to `process` updates on the EDT, allowing for you to update the UI as required.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to place a `JLabel` wherever you want it to be, then substitute the calls to `System.out.println("...");` to [`JLabel#setText(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)).

For example:

```
myLoggingLabel.setText("Path : ");
```

And you could initialize it as:

```
JLabel myLoggingLabel = new JLabel("");
```

So it looks like an "invisible" label.

You can also hide the events after certain time using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) following the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: The JLabel is in my View class and the message log are printed on another class (Capture class). Should I call the label from the view class?

Comment: For us to provide more specific help post a proper [mcve]. We don't know what the `Capture` class looks like... but you would need to call something like `capure.getStatus()` or similar where `getStatus()` method only returns the status you want to paint in the `JLabel`

Comment: @Krul: you should only call public methods of one object in another. So the class that holds the JLabel should make it a private instance field, and that class should have a `public void setStatusText(String text)` method or something similar where the label's text is set.

Comment: @Krul You `Capture` class should generate events/notifications which are independent from how the user might be notified. With this, your UI could monitor for updates and update the label's itself, but it would decouple the `Capture` class from the UI, allowing other implementations and methods for keeping the user in the loop of what's going on

Comment: The Capture class is the class that hold a stack representing cells in a path. paths are calculated checking neighbour cells and if their seeds are of the same player: say if all neighbour cells contain seeds of playerA, and at least one seed of playerB, then playerB seed is "captured". @Frakcool

Comment: Again, (re)read what a [mcve] is if you want more specific help following MadProgrammer and Hovercraft's suggestions in the comments above. As is, this is the best help we can provide

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @HovercraftFullOfEels, Madprogrammer and Frakcool

Comment: Frakcool* (Without `N`) :) You can still [edit] your question to provide more details including your code and we'll be glad to provide a more helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JLabel setText() method?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html

Comment: JTextArea will be better choice.

Comment: Probably, but he asked about JLabel's so that is why I mentioned JLabel setText() method, and the documentation.